# Java - Shaped Frame : Jaggered Edges & Applet

Tags: java, applet, shapes, minecraft, antialiasing

I was writing a redesigned frame, containing a Java Applet.
( In this case, it's a Minecraft Java Applet )

The frame have properties like `setUndecorated(true);`.

The components are disposed using absolute coordinates.
( => `setLayout(null);` & `element.setBounds(posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY);` )

I used a `setShape` on the JFrame to get some round corners.
Sadly, the frame's edgesare jagged, and that's kinda ugly.

---

Here's some representatives pics :

[Minecraft Frame http://nicnl.com/Autre/minecraftFrame.jpg](http://nicnl.com/Autre/minecraftFrame.jpg)
[Minecraft Frame Zoom http://nicnl.com/Autre/minecraftFrame_zoom.jpg](http://nicnl.com/Autre/minecraftFrame_zoom.jpg)

---

I searched over the web, and find a solution that should be implemented in the `paint(Graphics g)` method :

```
Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D)g;
RenderingHints renderingHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
graphics2D.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
```

This Java code should add Anti-Aliasing effect on my frame.
Sadly, this render properties only work on painted components.
And, obviously, the Minecraft Applet is not drawn using SWING, so that 'solution' isn't working at all.

So here's my question : is there any way to get this frame's corners prettier ?

<[ Thanks in advance =) ]>